# USB-to-RS232 on Android using Qt5.5

Tags: android, qt, serial-port, usb, qml

Qt claims "Qt is the leading independent technology for cross-platform development".
I would like to use QML in Qt5.5 to write a application to talk to a USB-to-RS232 device (like good old HyperTerminal) and run it only in two different platforms Windows-7 and Android!

If you have serial communication experience in Qt, can you advise me how to handle USB-to-RS232 interface BOTH in Windows and Androit using Qt5.5?
Working examples would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Well, asking for complete hardware support across platforms may be a bit too much to ask... Anyway, you should never have to deal with USB-to-RS232 devices directly; all modern platforms will pretent such a device is a 'regular' serial device. So start with QSerialPort.

Comment: @JvO, Thank you for your reply. 

Like WiFi and Bluetooth, most Windows and Android devices have USB ports and they support serial communication via USB. 

As you have already mentioned Qt provides QSerialPort class. But,  (I hope I am wrong), unfortunately, it seems to be that Qt do not support   their own QSerialPort in Android.

Have you ever managed to use QSerialPort on Android? 
Can you help me/us with an example app how to use QSerialPort on Android?

Thank you.

Comment: I have no experience with USB serial ports on Android; it may not be a common feature. I hooked up a USB-to-RS232 converter to a tablet and a phone; on the tablet the convertor LED lit up and I got /dev/ttyS0 device; on the phone nothing happened. I think you have to write your own wrapper for serial devices for Android, which shouldn't be too difficult by looking at QSerialPort for Linux.

Comment: I'm using QSerialPort on Android with Qt5 (with bluetooth serial port). It works fine. // edit - actualy I'm wrong - I'm using QBluetoothDevice with rs232 mode

Comment: @ Kamil Klimek, Thank you for your message. I need to use RS232 (i.e. cable connection; wireless communication is not acceptable for my app) between Android device and the external device. Therefore,  QBluetoothDevice is not a valid option for my Adroid app. I need to find a way to make QSerialPort to work on Android.

Comment: QtSerialPort is supported on Android since Qt5.2.

Comment: @FrankMeerkötter: Is QT fully supporting QSerialPort on Android? Can we access USB Serial port using the QSerialPort class? As per the link https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/android.html they don't support. Can you please provide the details on what they support.